# Is there any way to specify table prefixes in ActiveJDBC models?

Tags: activejdbc

Is there any way to change the table name of the models, or specify a table prefix, so that the model named People, for example, would reference the table TP_PEOPLE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way, you can use the  `@Table` annotation, such as:

```
@Table("TP_PEOPLE")
public class People extends Model {}
```

however, I would suggest to call your class `Person`, since the instance of this class represent a single row from your table:

```
@Table("TP_PEOPLE")
public class Person extends Model {}
```

so that your code will look:

```
List<Person> people = Person.where("ssn  = ?", ssn);
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!  BTW, my model actually is called Person.  Not sure what I was thinking.